# Wall breaker vs Giant against walls

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is it better to include wall breakers or use more giants for getting past walls? I normally use lots of giants and drop a healing spell on them as soon as they get to the first wall but then I recently tried wall breakers and they can be good, at least on the first set of walls. I'm just starting at T.H. 8

What tactics are more effective at getting past walls?

Comment: It takes 1-3 wall breakers to get through one set of walls, and they do so almost instantly if you can protect them. How long does it take for a group of Giants to break through? While both have advantages and disadvantages, it comes down to personal preference and how good you are at deploying them to go where you want them to.

Comment: use wall breakers with gap means see if mortar is fired then drop wb so they will be saved from mortar or from wiz then boom  you are in and also just don't use healing on giant earlier, only use when they are in red(low health) and also try to use rage too with wiz... bdw it depends on base to base.

Comment: @Leothelion the thing is, if there's other structures on the outside of the walls, then the wb take time to run to the walls, and this makes timing so they don't get hit my a mortar difficult. but you have a good point about saving healing spell until giants are lower on health...my thinking was use spells as soon as possible so highest number of troops are effected.

Comment: no. don't rush with spells or you can't be able to use them effectively. m using 2 rage 2 heal but first rage on giants, then heal and then again rage and heal so all spell will work perfactily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It depends on the base. If you can effectively distract defenses with a few giants to let your wall breakers easily target the walls you want, wall breakers are more valuable. If you can't giants are.

Long answer: There are some scenarios where taking wall breakers is ineffective. Some examples of this are if there is a lot of splash damage near the section of wall you wish to get through. Wizard towers and mortars can one shot a group of wall breakers moving in, and if you were counting on them breaking that wall, it may ruin your raid. A way to avoid this from happening is to send giants to the side of where you want the wall breakers to go. This will cause the giants to draw fire from the defenses to let the wall breakers easily destroy the wall, as it only takes 1-3 (in most cases, it takes 15 level 1 wall breakers to destroy max walls. See [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_Breaker) for a chart) Wall breakers to destroy a wall depending the the levels of both. The quick destruction of the walls may give you those extra few seconds you need to destroy the last few buildings for the three star (this is more of a factor the higher the level of the walls). However, this is not always possible, so taking the wall breakers would not help, and in that case more giants would be better.

Some things to consider: Using a rage spell with wall breakers can be helpful as it increases their damage and hit points and running speed which can prevent them from getting one shot, and help them more easily get through higher level walls. At th8 you can unlock earthquake spells, and 4 of them (of any level) can destroy any level walls, and act a pseudo jump spell. Also 2 wall breakers take 4 housing space, and 1 giant takes 5. 2 wall breakers is usually enough to take out most walls (provided your wall breakers are leveled up, and you are attacking a similarly leveled base).

Answer (score 0):

Wall breakers are best for giant based strategies. Giants can take a while to destroy buildings and multiple layers of walls will become a huge hassle for the attacker. It is best to bring about six to ten wall breakers to clear entrances into the deep layers of the base.

Deploy a giant then follow with two wall breakers to destroy the layer nearest the giant. As you steadily go through the base, add more wall breakers to allow further penetration. Deploy quickly and smartly or they can be one shot by mortars or traps.